# how to check whether quantity entered on form is greater than the stock quantity in database

Tags: php, stock

trying to check whether the quantity entered by user on form is greater than that in stock. if it is, then it should set quantity to STOCK VALUE on the form.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]))
{ 
    if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything   but       numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }

    $sqlquan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquan)) {
            $item_id= $row["id"];
            $stock= $row["stock"];
        }
            if ($quantity > $stock)
        {echo "much";
        $quantity=$stock;}

    $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust  its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
}
```

The problem is I have 2 items in the cart. The 1st one's stock value is 15 and the second one's stock value is 23. If i enter a quantity greater than 15 for the first product, it works well(sets quantity to 15). But if i enter a value greater than 15 but less than 23 for the second product, *it compares against the stock value of the first product and resets to 15 again.*

Comment: What is your question? How is this code not performing as expected? Any error messages?

Comment: problem is i have 2 items in cart. 1st one's stock value is 15 and the second one's stock value is 23. if i enter a quantity greater than 15 for the first product, it works well(sets quantity to 15). but if i enter a value greater than 15 but less than 23 for the second product, it compares against the stock value of the first product and resets to 15 again.

Comment: @user3525190 `$_POST['quantity']` doesn't seem to be tied to any item, so you first need to make an array of quantity that corresponds to all the items.

Comment: sorry  i can't show the whole codes.lot of lines.<form action="cart.php" method="post">
  <input name="quantity" id="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
  <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
  <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
  </form>

Comment: You can always edit your original question to add a substantial amount of new code or new info. If you have small code snippets, you can make them appear as code in a comment by using backticks `like this`.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned your code quite a bit. Hope this works.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_array"])) {
    if(isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && !empty($_POST['item_to_adjust'])) {
        $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
        $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['quantity']); // filter everything but numbers
        if ($quantity >= 100) $quantity = 99;
        if (empty($quantity) || $quantity < 1) $quantity = 1;

        $sqlquan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_to_adjust' LIMIT 1"); // You previously used id='$item_id', I think you meant $item_to_adjust

        // Since you have limited your query to only have 1 result, there is no need to use a while loop
        // also note in your original code the while loop was closed prematurely.
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquan);
        // No need to create new variables when $row is accessible directly

        if($quantity > $row["stock"]) {
            echo "Requested Quantity exceeds currently available Stock.<br>";
            $quantity = $row["stock"];
            echo "Quantity set to maximum available stock of ".$row["stock"]."<br>";
        }

        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as &$each_item) {   // Referenced variable &$each_item so you do not have to use complicated array functions
            if($each_item['item_id'] == $item_to_adjust) {
                $each_item['quantity'] = $quantity;
                break; // Terminates the foreach loop
            }
        } // close foreach loop
    } else {
        echo("Invalid Item ID");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3525190 Apologies in advance if it doesn't work. Its 5:17am here been awake 24 hours since.